# Nikkor 70-200 f2.8 VRII - Aperture not working?

Tags: nikon, repair, equipment-damage, telephoto

My question is pretty straightforward: this lens' aperture stopped working for some reason. What could it be the cause?

Me and a friend of mine tried it in studio, attached to a D750, and when we selected f2.8, it didn't make any difference to f22.
We tried other lenses and they all worked fine, and before you ask, yes we were shooting totally manual (time-priority or program modes).

1 month ago the lens worked perfectly fine on my D610 and the lens has never had problems of fungus, misuse, or whatsoever.

Comment: **T** and **P** modes are semi-automatic modes. **M** mode is totally manual (assuming *Auto ISO* is not enabled).

Comment: If you hold the unmounted lens in your hand and move the aperture linkage while looking through the lens what happens?

Comment: Dear Michael, I just did what you asked... and this brought the lens back to life! Now it works!

Comment: It sounds like Michael's answer addressed your problem. Would you mind accepting his answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try holding the unmounted lens and moving the aperture linkage while looking through the lens. If it is a little stiff at first and then moves freely after a couple of cycles from one end of the lever's movement to the other then that's probably all you need to do.

Next time be sure the lens is in dry air and at ambient temperature before storing it away for extended periods of time. Moisture can condense in the lens otherwise and lead to the problem you experienced. It's also possible the lubricants inside the lens may have dried out a little. If you're sure you're storing it properly and it happens again on a more and more frequent basis it may be time to have a qualified service center clean and lubricate the internal parts of the lens.